# Resource is out of sync with the file system application.properties

Tags: java, maven, email, spring-boot

I have done a pull from the branch master from gitlab. However, after doing this, an application.properties error has shown up. I didn't understand what caused the problem because it is fine with all others that I work with.

It tells me that the problem is within my imports of email libraries, but its dependencies and configs in application.propreties are there.

Here are some captures of my errors :

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Application.properties :

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================

# Set here configurations for the database connection

# Connection url for the database "netgloo_blog"
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deliveryeat?useSSL=false

# Username and password
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================

spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# the project
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# ===============================
# = Thymeleaf configurations
# ===============================
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# ==============================================================
# = Spring Security / Queries for AuthenticationManagerBuilder  
# ==============================================================
spring.queries.users-query=select email, password, is_account_activated from user where email=?
spring.queries.livreurs-query=select email, password, is_activated from livreur where email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.email, r.role from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.user_id=ur.user_id) inner join role r on(ur.role_id=r.role_id) where u.email=?
view raw

# ===============================
# TOMCAT
# ===============================
server.address=127.0.0.1
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true

# ===============================
# SMTP EMAIL
# ===============================

spring.mail.host = 
spring.mail.username = 
spring.mail.password = 
spring.mail.port: 587
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required: true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.scheduler.enabled: true
spring.mail.scheduler.priorityLevels: 2

# ===============================
# = LOGGING
# ===============================
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR

# ===============================
# = LOGGING
# ===============================
deliveryeat.path = http://localhost:8080/DeliveryEatWeb
deliveryeat.name = DeliveryEat
deliveryeat.email = support@deliveryeat.fr
deliveryeat.email.sender = DeliveryEat Service
deliveryeat.email.subject.confirmation = DeliveryEat Service - Confirmation Email
deliveryeat.email.subject.reset = DeliveryEat Service - Réinitialisation mot de passe
deliveryeat.email.subject.postlivreur = Nouvelle demande de préinscription livreur
deliveryeat.email.subject.postrestaurant = Nouvelle demande de partenariat - Restaurant
#serverurl.path = http://www.deliveryeat.fr/DeliveryEatWeb
images.path = ../../

# ===============================
# = STRIP JAVA - Module de payement
# ===============================

STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = sk_test_EYI7cS2cGRznP4sl9EGVcGtG
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY= pk_test_3wSzlOwgECyTNbVtcdQBYShR

# ===============================
# = Key  google api 
# ===============================

deliveryeat.map.key= AIzaSyDI6XZYLZUTAQjw2H6z6B_hrN3XnYzs1Ks

# ===============================
# = Roles
# ===============================

deliveryeat.role.admin = ADMIN
deliveryeat.role.transporter = TRANSPORTER
deliveryeat.role.restaurant = RESTAURANT
deliveryeat.role.customer = CUSTOMER

# ===============================
# = Loj4j Properties
# ===============================

# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1} - %m%n
```

Comment: Might want to attempt purging the local maven repo for all or the specific artifacts

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html

Comment: I  don't know how to use nvm command , It's a total stranger to me , can you help me plz

Comment: I resolved the problem by adding com.google.guava dependency but the tomcat error still exists "failed to start"

Comment: Just for curiosity... it's really named application.`propreties` or application.`properties`? The right is `application.properties`, but if is a typo, this might be the reason.

Comment: the name is right in my project (application.properties) I just wrote it wrong here